# JDO/Datanucleus error : Field "..." is declared as a reference type (interface/Object) but no implementation classes of "..." have been found?

Tags: java, orm, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

I'm new to JDO specification and Datanucleus implementations and i'm struggling right now in my Project with the error described above.

What steps will reproduce the Problem:

1- Defining a Class "DefaultDiffTask":

`@PersistenceCapable
    public class DefaultDiffTask implements IDiffTask, Serializable {
    @Persistent
    protected IDiffTaskTarget diffTaskTarget;
    @Persistent
    protected String diffTaskId;

```
protected IDiffTaskPhasesMgr diffTaskPhasesMgr;

@Persistent
protected IDiffTaskType diffTaskType;

@Persistent
protected String taskCreationTime;

public DefaultDiffTask() {

this.diffTaskTarget = new DefaultDiffTaskTarget(
    new DefaultPageStateLocation(""), new DefaultPageStateLocation(
        ""));
this.diffTaskPhasesMgr = new DefaultDiffTaskPhasesMgr(this); //
DiffTaskUtility.createTaskPhasesMgr(this);
this.diffTaskType = new DefaultDiffTaskType(
    DiffTaskTypeEnum.CRAWLER_BASED_DIFF);
this.taskCreationTime = (new Date()).toString();
this.diffTaskId = this.generateDiffTaskId();

}

public DefaultDiffTask(IDiffTaskTarget diffTaskArea,
    IDiffTaskType diffTaskType) {
this.diffTaskTarget = diffTaskArea;
this.diffTaskPhasesMgr = new DefaultDiffTaskPhasesMgr(this); // DiffTaskUtility.createTaskPhasesMgr(this);
this.diffTaskType = diffTaskType;
this.taskCreationTime = (new Date()).toString();
this.diffTaskId = this.generateDiffTaskId();
}
...........`
```

2- try to retrieve some previously stored object with :

```
PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper
    .getPersistenceManagerFactory(.....);
// Persistence of a Product and a Book.
PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
try {
    tx.begin();
    System.out.println("Retrieving Extent for Default");
    Extent e = pm.getExtent(DefaultDiffTask.class, true);
    Iterator iter = e.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = iter.next();
    System.out.println(">  "
        + ((DefaultDiffTask) obj).getDiffTaskId());
    }
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception thrown during retrieval of Extent : "
        + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (tx.isActive())
    tx.rollback();
    pm.close();
}
```

the expected output:

Retrieving Extent for Default:
something here

But i get he following exception:

`Retrieving Extent for Default
Exception thrown during retrieval of Extent : Field "net.she.sw.diff2w3c.diff.tsk.DefaultDiffTask.diffTaskTarget" is declared as a reference type (interface/Object) but **no implementation classes** of "net.she.sw.diff2w3c.diff.tsk.target.IDiffTaskTarget" have been found!`

my point is, i have some implementation of the interface   net.she.sw.diff2w3c.diff.tsk.DefaultDiffTask.diffTaskTarget which have the annotation  "@PersistenceCapable" like:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class DefaultDiffTaskTarget extends AbstractDiffTaskTarget {
public DefaultDiffTaskTarget(IDiffTaskTargetStateLocation firstLocation,
    IDiffTaskTargetStateLocation secondLocation) {
super(firstLocation, secondLocation);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

or

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class DefaultDiffTaskTarget extends AbstractDiffTaskTarget {
```

or

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class PageAreaTarget extends AbstractDiffTaskTarget {
```

this object are injected in the constructors (default and custom) when a DefaulfDiffTask get created...

so my point is

- Why this error ?
- is it something i am missing ?
- all the implementation of the implementations of the interface IDiffTaskTargetare present in the classpath AND have the Annotations for the JDO/Datanucleus to work

i know the problem is on my code and not on the side of JDO/Datanucleus, 
and i will be greatful for any given help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does DataNucleus know of your other classes ? you expect it to guess where they are ? Why not just specify them as per the docs  http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/interfaces.html

Comment: I have similar problems when i run a spring-boot project in maven. Actually it runs well if i run it though eclipse run as java application. But in `mvn spring-boot:run` style i need to add `implementation-classes`. However, even if i added the key. it still throws errors that "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.identity.OIDImpl cannot be cast to mydomain.interface". How can i solve that?